# does socket.io let you send custom data to a tcp port?

Tags: javascript, html, security, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to determine whether it is possible to send custom data to a given TCP port from a web-page with JavaScript (e.g. with a socket.io library).

The WebSocket API is said to require a handshake with a web-server, with an HTTP/1.1 `Connection: Upgrade` header, prior to letting you pass messages back and forth.  So, it seems like it won't do (unless the HTTP-based handshake can somehow be avoided).

But socket.io has other transports and features, too.  So, does it let you send any kind of custom data to any TCP port?  In other words, does it let you operate on raw TCP sockets, similar to `nc` (netcat) on UNIX?  Is there a way to operate on raw TCP sockets with JavaScript in general?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use vanilla browser-based Javascript to send custom protocols directly via TCP.  You can do it using Javascript in Node.js, though, so one easy thing would be to accept websocket connections in a Node server you write which then proxies them as plain TCP to the real service.